# form tag is not getting added for the first row

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

The form tag is not getting added for the first row in my html page.

JSP code:

```
   <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="lightblue">

        <th>Mens Cloth</th>
        <th>Womens Cloth</th>
        <th>Others</th>
        <th>Total Clothes</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>User Details</th>
        <th>Submit</th>

    </tr>


    <%-- <c:forEach var="order" items="${orderedList}">
        <div></div>
    </c:forEach> --%>
    <c:if test="${empty orderedList}">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">No Results found</td>
        </tr>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${! empty orderedList}">
        <c:forEach var="order" items="${orderedList}">
            <form:form method="post" action="updateStatus"
                    commandName="washingOrder">

            <tr>


                    <form:hidden path="orderNo" value="${order.orderNo}" />
                    <td><c:out value="${order}"></c:out></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${order.mensCloth}"></c:out></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${order.womensCloth}"></c:out></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${order.otherClothes}"></c:out></td>


                    <td><c:out value="${order.totalClothes}"></c:out></td>
                    <td><form:select path="orderStatus">
                            <c:forEach items="${orderList}" var="orderList">
                                <option
                                    <c:if test="${orderList.key eq order.orderStatus}">selected</c:if>
                                    value="${orderList.key}">${orderList.value}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </form:select></td>

                    <td><a href="getUserDetails?order_id=${order.orderNo}">UserDetails</a></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>

            </tr>
     </form:form>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
    </table>
```

When this converted into HTML page the form tag is getting missed for the first row.

```
                    <input id="orderNo" name="orderNo" value="1" type="hidden">
                    <td>WashingOrder [orderNo=1, totalClothes=9, mensCloth=3, womensCloth=3, Others=3, deliveryDate=2015-01-01 00:09:00.0, orderStatus=Ordered]</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>3</td>


                    <td>9</td>
                    <td><select id="orderStatus" name="orderStatus">

                                <option value="PU">Pick-Up</option>

                                <option value="OD">Ordered</option>

                                <option value="WP">Washing Processing</option>

                                <option value="PK">Packing</option>

                                <option value="OTW">On the way</option>

                                <option value="DD">Delivered</option>

                        </select></td>

                    <td><a href="getUserDetails?order_id=1">UserDetails</a></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>

            </tr>
```

For the remaining rows it is getting added and i am able to process the request.

Any thing I have missed out to add in jsp tag?

Comment: The code you are supplying looks incomplete. Please supply the full code of the JSP or at least a syntactically complete subset.

Comment: full code of the JSP pasted

Comment: no `<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>` ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the problem might be that you only have opening tags for `<form:form>` and `<form:hidden>`. The `<form:select>` which has its closing tag is rendered correctly in HTML.

Comment: If that is teh case the form tag should not add to the second row of the table. The problem here is form tag not get added to only first row.